# Function to remove spaces in S3 file header

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, amazon-s3, parquet

What is the simple way to remove spaces from my parquet file header(like "I D", "NA M E"). stored in s3. We want to achieve this with less compute effort.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove spaces from my parquet file header"? Can you provide an example? If you want to modify a file stored in Amazon S3, it would be necessary to download the file, modify it and upload it again. You would need some form of compute for this (eg Amazon EC2 instance, Fargate, AWS Lambda, or on your own computer).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. We are receiving unwanted spaces in header like "I D", "NA M E". Since the files are very large and the issue is only with the header, we are looking for a simple solution to remove these spaces with less compute.

Comment: The easiest way is to fix the files _before_ they are uploaded to Amazon S3, or to find the root cause of the the problem. Once in S3, you'll need some form of compute to retrieve, process and re-upload the files.